# Retrieve entity_id based on specific conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table named `entity_changes` with the following structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE entity_changes (
    entity_id INTEGER,
    raw_time BIGINT,
    resolved_datetime TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
    old_phase VARCHAR(255),
    new_phase VARCHAR(255)
);
```

This table tracks changes in the phases of entities over time. Each row represents a change in the phase of an entity with the `entity_id`, along with timestamps and phase details.

I'm trying to formulate a query that retrieves `entity_id` values based on:

1. The `new_phase` is 'Accept'.
2. There is no subsequent change from 'Accept' to 'Review' for the same `entity_id`.

For example, given the sample data below:

| entity_id | raw_time | resolved_datetime | old_phase | new_phase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1683722752681 | 2023-05-10T14:45:52.681+02 | NULL | Log |
| 1 | 1683722755440 | 2023-05-10T14:45:55.44+02 | Log | Approve |
| 1 | 1683722758915 | 2023-05-10T14:45:58.915+02 | Approve | Fulfill |
| 1 | 1687773706503 | 2023-06-26T12:01:46.503+02 | Fulfill | Accept |
| 1 | 1687774413272 | 2023-06-26T12:13:33.272+02 | Accept | Review |
| 2 | 1683722752681 | 2023-05-10T14:45:52.681+02 | NULL | Log |
| 2 | 1683722755440 | 2023-05-10T14:45:55.44+02 | Log | Approve |
| 2 | 1683722758915 | 2023-05-10T14:45:58.915+02 | Approve | Accept |
| 2 | 1687773706503 | 2023-06-26T12:01:46.503+02 | Accept | Review |
| 2 | 1687774413272 | 2023-06-26T12:13:33.272+02 | Review | Accept |

I would like to retrieve the `entity_id` values 2, since for entity_id 1, there's a subsequent change from 'Accept' to 'Review'.

Could you please help me formulate a SQL query to achieve this?

db fiddle : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fNLaxsA1MFM5oSWztmqfad/0

Comment: Why return `entity_id` values 2 but not values 1. You say because `entity_id` 1 has a *subsequent change from 'Accept' to 'Review'*. But `entity_id`  2 also has that same subsequent change. Do you actually mean where the change 'Accept' to 'Review' is the last entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exist is probably the easiest way to go.

```
select * 
  from entity_changes t1
 where t1.new_phase = 'accept'
   and not exists
         ( select 1
             from entity_changes t2
            where t2.entity_id = t1.entity_id
              and t2.resolved_datetime > t1.resolved_datetime
              and t2.new_phase = 'review'
         )
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a window function in case you will need to add new measures to this query that looks over the life of an entity.  I put a couple of example columns in there for you to show what I mean and left out filtering on `current_phase = 'Accept'`:

```
with changes as ( 
  select distinct entity_id, 
         last_value(new_phase) over w as current_phase,
         sum(((old_phase, new_phase) = ('Accept', 'Review'))::int) over w as count_accept_to_review,
         sum((new_phase = 'Accept')::int) over w as count_accepted
    from entity_changes
  window w as (partition by entity_id order by raw_time rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)
)
select * 
  from changes 
;
```

[Updated fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fNLaxsA1MFM5oSWztmqfad/0)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
SELECT * FROM entity_changes
WHERE new_phase='Accept' AND raw_time 
 IN(SELECT MAX(raw_time) FROM 
 entity_changes GROUP BY entity_id)
ORDER BY entity_id, raw_time;
```

Comment: Just for the sake of nitpicking, OP said Accept reverting to Review is the case to exclude. So this might exclude cases of Accept to Approve. Or, you could have a case where completely different entity_id had it's latest event at the same raw_time and this would incorrectly include it.